# Compute Euler characteristic of a compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

We have the manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$ given by
$$M=\{(x,y,z,w)|2x^2+2=2z^2+w^2,3x^2+y^2=z^2+w^2\}$$
How could I compute the Euler characteristic? I've no idea computing the homology group of this kind of manifold. Should I use de Rham cohomology? Since I'm not quite familiar with de Rham, I'm not sure if this can be solved by the tool. Any hints or answers are welcomed, thanks!

Comment: you could use de rham cohomology; the alternating sum of the dimensions of the cohomology groups is the Euler characteristic.

Comment: @Herrmann Surely I know I could use de Rham, but I have no idea finding some closed but not exact form and prove all these forms are generated by the form I found.

Comment: at the end you say "I'm not sure if this can be solved by the tool".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINTS:** This is going to be a common, everyday surface, so you need to do some algebraic manipulations and more multivariable analysis. You should first prove that the surface is compact. Then you will need to recognize that this surface is a branched double cover of the $2$-sphere and use basic facts about Euler characteristic.

Comment: Thanks for your Hint! I've tried working on your claim "this surface is a branched double cover" but could not find why. Would you mind elaborating it? Or give me some reference of similar simple examples? Thanks!

Comment: Step 1: Show that this surface in $\Bbb R^4$ lies over the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ in $\Bbb R^3$.  Step 2: Over most points of that sphere there are two points $(x,y,z,w)$ in your surface. Find the points over which there is just one point. Step 3: Think about simplicial Euler characteristic to get a modification of the formula for Euler characteristic of a covering space.

Comment: That's great! Thanks!